# Using GREP and returning the following text. (DNS Lookup)

Tags: linux, bash, dns

I am trying to use a script to run two linux dns commands WHOIS and DIG.

So far my script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $1
do      
    reg1=`whois $i`
    echo "*********WHOIS Results for $i*********"
    echo -e "[$i]\n$reg1"
    for j in 4.2.2.3 
    do
        reg=`dig any @$j $i `
        echo -e "[$j]$reg"
    done
done
```

Now I am looking for a command to replace the '4.2.2.3' that I can use to search the output of the previous command and return part of this line: 'Name Server: A.DNS.HOSTWAY.NET'. The 'Name Server:' is what I will search for and it should return the following text, stopping at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting what you want to do correctly, you should be able to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $1
do      
    reg1=`whois $i`
    echo "*********WHOIS Results for $i*********"
    echo -e "[$i]\n$reg1"
    grep 'Name Server' <<< "$reg1" | awk '{print $3}' | while read j
    do
        echo -e "[$j]$(dig any @$j $i)"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you could try something like :

```
[ ~]$ echo "Name Server: A.DNS.HOSTWAY.NET"|egrep -o "Name Server:\ *[A-Za-z\.]*"|awk -F ": *" '{print $2}'
A.DNS.HOSTWAY.NET
```

But I'm not sure I understood everything, including the fact of using a `for` loop on a single value.